# Divi theme + woocommerce + mercadopago

Tags: wordpress, mercadopago, woocommerce

quería saber si alguien logró montar con éxito una tienda usando woocommerce, mercadopago y el theme Divi. 
Si así lo fuera, podrían decirme si fue complicado o si pudieron montar la tienda sin problemas.
Gracias!

Comment: Deberías mejorar tu pregunta, así como está cualquiera podría responderte con un sí o un no y sería perfectamente correcta. Trata de explicar que has intentado y que problemas enfrentas en sí.

Comment: solo necesito saber si es posible montar una tienda con esas características sin tener problemas grandes de programación. En internet no encontré una respuesta o tema que trate puntualmente mi pregunta. Si la respuesta es afirmativa, voy a generar nuevas preguntas sobre el tema. Si es muy complejo montar la tienda con divi elegiré otro theme... Es una pregunta tipo "puntapié inicial".

Comment: de cualquier manera deberías reescribir la pregunta, no quieres saber si alguien lo ha hecho, sino el cómo.

Comment: Hola @JuanPablo, bienvenido a [es.so]! Te comento que seguimos otro mecanismo en el sitio. Esperamos que muestres qué estás intentando, dónde estás teniendo problemas, qué problemas específicos, y recién ahí ver posibles respuestas concretas (no es un reemplazo de Google). Quizás te sea útil leer [ask]. Si se te ocurre cómo modificar tu pregunta para seguir estos lineamientos, encontrarás el enlace a **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta.

Comment: ok, voy a chequear donde tengo la traba puntualmente y actualizaré la pregunta con mas info.

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo solucioné, tenia un problema en el carrito de compra, el boton de "agregar al carrito", hacía un bucle el botón (la animación del js) y no me dejaba agregar el producto. Edité el producto de nuevo, modifiqué algunos datos y no se como se solucionó.
Dejo la respuesta por si a alguien le sirve.

Comment: ¿La animación del JS era algo que añadiste en tu proyecto o que venía directamente en Divi/woocommerce/mercadopago?

Comment: Es un efecto .js que ya trae Divi en su elemento button y se lo aplica al botón "agregar al carrito" de woommerce. No era algo de mercadopago, creo. Aún así me lo hace cuando estoy editando el theme desde el menu Divi---Divi Customizer.